# solve sympy equation results in an error on numpy array dimensions

Tags: arrays, numpy, sympy

I'm currently trying to solve a system of equations using sympy (following [this lecture on scientific python](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-5-Sympy.ipynb)) and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VMT.py", line 13, in <module>
    [Vmc, Vgp, tmc, tgp])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 311, in solve
    _assertRank2(a, b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 155, in _assertRank2
    two-dimensional' % len(a.shape)
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

My code is:

```
from sympy import *
from pylab import *

Vmc=Symbol('Vmc')
Vgp=Symbol('Vgp')
tmc=Symbol('tmc')
tgp=Symbol('tgp')

solve([-Vmc + (((2300**10)*(tmc - 85))/(0.02*85))**(1/10), 
  -Vgp + (((6900**10)*(tgp - 85))/(0.02*0.85))**(1/10), 
  -Vmc + 12000*(((2.76/(tgp - tmc)) - 7)/(16 - 7))**(1/10), 
  -Vgp - Vmc + 12000], 
  [Vmc, Vgp, tmc, tgp])
```

I know this seems to be an issue with how I set up the solve function, but I'm a bit confused as how to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from using the

```
from pylab import *
```

line right after

```
from sympy import *
```

You've created a namespace collision, because `solve` exists both under `pylab` (where it is in fact an alias for `numpy.linalg.solve`) as well as `sympy`.

You should try to avoid such generic imports.

For example, this will work:

```
from sympy import *  # still not a big fan of this
import pylab

Vmc=Symbol('Vmc')
Vgp=Symbol('Vgp')
tmc=Symbol('tmc')
tgp=Symbol('tgp')

solve([-Vmc + (((2300**10)*(tmc - 85))/(0.02*85))**(1/10), 
  -Vgp + (((6900**10)*(tgp - 85))/(0.02*0.85))**(1/10), 
  -Vmc + 12000*(((2.76/(tgp - tmc)) - 7)/(16 - 7))**(1/10), 
  -Vgp - Vmc + 12000], 
  [Vmc, Vgp, tmc, tgp])
```

Your system of equations might not have a solution though.

Comment: Thanks!
Yeah fair... I was doing it in Mathematica at first, but chalked up the infinite runtime to just Mathematica being janky (my computer and it don't always get along)